# Datagram Socket bound to specific interface is not receiving in java. But UDP is perfectly receiving data in wire shark

Tags: java, sockets, udp, datagram

I am trying to get data from a UDP server. I have made the client udp socket for receiving data from UDP-server. Perfectly getting data in wire-shark but the udp.receive(package) is not getting data.

I have already tried the different ips like 192.168.0.252 is the source in the wire shark and my local IP(127.0.0.1). I have also tried without interface.

```
      NetworkInterface nif = NetworkInterface.getByName("enp2s0");

    if(nif==null){
        System.err.println("Error getting the Network Interface");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Preparing to using the interface: "+nif.getName());
    Enumeration<InetAddress> nifAddresses = nif.getInetAddresses();
    InetSocketAddress inetAddr= new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",6723);

    //socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(nifAddresses.nextElement(), 0));
    this.udpSocket = new DatagramSocket(inetAddr);
    System.out.println("Interface setted");
```

//Till this code is initialised perfectly

```
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

        // blocks until a packet is received
        udpSocket.receive(packet);
       //Data stucking here
        msg = new String(packet.getData()).trim();

        System.out.println(
                "Message from " + packet.getAddress().getHostAddress() + ": " + msg);
```

The code remain in running mode but not receiving data

[image]

Comment: If you bind to 127.0.0.1 you can only receive from the local host. Bind to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: i have tried that also but still not working

Comment: These are multicasts. You need to use a `MulticastSocket` and join the group to receive them.

Comment: That's working using multicastSocket. Thank you very much. Can you explain why i am getting problem with DataGram. And it is working with multicast

Comment: I don't know what you're asking me that I haven't already answered. It's multicast, so you have to join the group, so you have to use a `MulticastSocket`.